# How to properly serve a PDF file

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, encoding

I am using .NET 3.5 ASP.NET.  Currently my web site serves a PDF file in the following manner:

`context.Response.WriteFile(@"c:\blah\blah.pdf");`

This works great.  However, I'd like to serve it via the `context.Response.Write(char [], int, int)` method.

So I tried sending out the file via

```
byte [] byteContent = File.ReadAllBytes(ReportPath);
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
char[] charContent = encoding.GetChars(byteContent);
context.Response.Write(charContent, 0, charContent.Length);
```

That did not work (e.g. browser's PDF plugin complains that the file is corrupted).

So I tried the Unicode approach:

```
byte [] byteContent = File.ReadAllBytes(ReportPath);
UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
char[] charContent = encoding.GetChars(byteContent);
context.Response.Write(charContent, 0, charContent.Length);
```

which also did not work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not convert the bytes into characters, that is why it becomes "corrupted". Even though ASCII characters are stored in bytes the actual ASCII character set is limited to 7 bits. Thus, converting a byte stream with [the ASCIIEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.aspx) will effectively remove the 8th bit from each byte.

The bytes should be written to [the OutputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream.aspx) stream of the Response instance.

Instead of loading all bytes from the file upfront, which could possibly consume a lot of memory, reading the file in chunks from a stream is a better approach. Here's a sample of how to read from one stream and then write to another:

```
void LoadStreamToStream(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream)
{
    const int bufferSize = 64 * 1024;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    while (true)
    {
        var bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        if ((bytesRead == 0) || (bytesRead < bufferSize))
            break;
    }
}
```

You can then use this method to load the contents of your file directly to the Response.OutputStream

```
LoadStreamToStream(fileStream, Response.OutputStream);
```

Better still, here's a method opening a file and loading its contents to a stream:

```
void LoadFileToStream(string inputFile, Stream outputStream)
{
    using (var streamInput = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        LoadStreamToStream(streamInput, outputStream);
        streamInput.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This worked great.  Can you elaborate on 2 things? Can I delete the file after calling LoadFileToStream, and then Response.Flush?  And why does converting chars to bytes cause corruption.  Are they not both 8 bits?

Comment: You can absolutely delete the file after LFTS, if you no longer need it around that is.

Comment: Elaborated on the encoding problem in my answer

Comment: No encoding. You really don't want to convert the binary stream into some other format, it will make the file unreadable, as your experience with the PDF file shows.

Comment: Understood.  I didn't really grok what encoding did, since I never had to use it before.  I get it now, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You may also need to set the ContentType by doing something like this:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

Answer (score 1):

Building upon [Peter Lillevold's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35245/peter-lillevold) answer, I went and just made some extension methods for his above functions.

```cs
public static void WriteTo(this Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream)
{
    const int bufferSize = 64 * 1024;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    while (true)
    {
        var bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        if ((bytesRead == 0) || (bytesRead < bufferSize)) break;
    }
}

public static void WriteToFromFile(this Stream outputStream, string inputFile)
{
    using (var inputStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        inputStream.WriteTo(outputStream);
        inputStream.Close();
    }
}
```