# Make a client download a file from a path that is not publicly accessible?

Tags: c#

I'm looking to implement a way to keep files private so they cant be publicly re-downloaded and only allow the server side code (like a button) to pull them from a private directory for the client on a one time basis.

Is that even possible?

Even if the folder is publicly available, What is a good way of firing an event that makes how many times the file has been downloaded so i can track that and make a service that deletes them after they've reached a download limit? I suppose i could just do a Response.redirect to the file and then the logic to track how many times its been downloaded. But is that the way you would do it?

EDIT: After some digging i've found a solution. I know many of you have downvoted this for not including sample code but I would appreciate if you can upvote it back for sharing the code I ended up using for it, since it works quite well.

```
String FileName = "File.zip";
            String FilePath = "C:/Test/" + FileName; //Replace this
            System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.ClearContent();
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
            response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
```

Comment: Where do you use C# on the client ot server site?

Comment: How do you host your data? In IIS or selfhosted in WCF? There are serveral options...

Comment: A little more effort in description and Tags and it would almost look like a question.

Comment: If you don't use any authentication mechanism, you can not do anything to prevent your file from being downloaded other that hardening the life for hacker

Comment: OK Let me explain it in another sense then.  Even if the folder is publicly available, What is a good way of firing an event that makes how many times the file has been downloaded so i can track that and make a service that deletes them after they've reached a download limit? I suppose i could just do a Response.redirect to the file and then the logic to track how many times its been downloaded. But is that the way you would do it?

Comment: @L.B: I beg to differ. You can restrict the folder and allow downloads through a handler.

Comment: DanC: Use the edit link to update the actual question. Don't provide essential info in comments.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, No, If you allow it to be downloadable somehow(by clicking a button etc), then no way to stop hackers. You probably know, this is why video/file downloaders exist.

Comment: @L.B: Odie has an answer below. True, that just shifts the issue to access to the handler. But the OP would be able to count and delete as requested.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Even counting may not be accurate if it is requested as multi-part.

Comment: @DanC. Please post your solution as an answer instead of editing it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging i've found a solution. I know many of you have downvoted this for not including sample code but I would appreciate if you can upvote it back for sharing the code I ended up using for it, since it works quite well.

```
String FileName = "File.zip";
            String FilePath = "C:/Test/" + FileName; //Replace this
            System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.ClearContent();
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
            response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
```

Answer (score 2):

Feed the file through a asp.net generic handler by writing it directly to the response stream. Then you would have full control over the public access to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've never actually done this, but I know how it is done.

Say the directory of your website is `C:\Sites\DanC\www>`. The outside world would see this as [www.DanC.com](http://www.DanC.com), or whatever.

Create a webpage for your download with the link, button, etc. called [download.aspx](http://www.DanC.com/download.aspx).

Your file is not in this directory, though. Your file is here: `C:\Sites\DanC\data>` There is no way someone can get from [www.DanC.com](http://www.DanC.com) up one level to get into your `data` directory.

Do you see that?

Now, whenever someone activates your download link (button, etc), your code would take the file from `C:\Sites\DanC\data>` and serve that to the client.

A nice example of how to serve your data to your client is [>> HERE <<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169433/how-to-properly-serve-a-pdf-file).

Comment: I would just want to show how it can be downloaded if you had sample server. Just drop a comment when you have one.

Comment: This would work great, except it outputs the file to the web browser directly.  That would work find if this were a PDF or something streamable, but I am looking for the user to get a save dialog.  Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Dan, see this link: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/21/Downloading-a-File-with-a-Save-As-Dialog-in-ASPNET