# stop unauthorized file download in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web-config

I have a `login.aspx` page with custom textbox for username and password i.e. no `loginview`
after supplying correct username and pwd i assign a `sessionid` which is used to visit other  pages on website.

Now to download a `file (1234)` i redierct the user to `~/download.aspx?fileid=1234`, on this page i check the session id and send the user to file url i.e. `~/file/1234.pdf`.
if some one dirctly enters file url, then i am unable to stop him.
plase guide me on how to do this...

P.S. : i have read about `authentication rule` in `web.config` file but dont know how to mark user as authenticated ones he supplies correct username and password at login. (i am only checking username and pwd from database and redirecting to home page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your authentication strategy is fairly weak. You should be bounding areas of your site (namely the files directory in this instance) with roles and assigning users to them.

However, to get around the more immediate problem, simply disable the outside world from getting to the files directory and when they hit `~/download.aspx?fileid=1234` just serve them the file. You can find instructions for this here: [How to properly serve a PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169433/how-to-properly-serve-a-pdf-file)

Comment: Restrict the file folders for any access and use response.writefile from the files folder in download.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

Look for point 4 in that article under - "Code the Event Handler So That It Validates the User Credentials", it explains you how to set authentication cookie after validating user

Code to look at:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
      string cookiestr;
      HttpCookie ck;
      tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUserName.Value, DateTime.Now, 
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), chkPersistCookie.Checked, "your custom data");
      cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
      ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
      if (chkPersistCookie.Checked)
      ck.Expires=tkt.Expiration;    
            ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath; 
      Response.Cookies.Add(ck);
```

What you can do is:

```
1. Enable form authentication in web.config
2. deny anonymous access to downloads folder
3. When user authenticates, set authentication cookie and redirect user to download folder
4. download folder now can only be accessed by logged in user and id
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code I use in my projects

```
void ServeFile(string fname, bool forceDownload)
{
 if(UserHasPermission(fname))
 {
  DownloadFile(fname,forceDownload);
 }
 else
 {
  ShowMessage("You have no permission");
 }
}

private void DownloadFile( string fname, bool forceDownload )
{
  string path = MapPath( fname );
  string name = Path.GetFileName( path );
  string ext = Path.GetExtension( path );
  string type = "";
  // set known types based on file extension  
  if ( ext != null )
  {
    switch( ext.ToLower() )
    {
    case ".htm":
    case ".html":
      type = "text/HTML";
      break;

    case ".txt":
      type = "text/plain";
      break;

    case ".doc":
    case ".rtf":
      type = "Application/msword";
      break;
    case ".pdf":
      type = "Application/pdf";
      break;
    }
  }
  if ( forceDownload )
  {
    Response.AppendHeader( "content-disposition",
        "attachment; filename=" + name );
  }
  if ( type != "" )   
    Response.ContentType = type;
  Response.WriteFile( path );
  Response.End();    
}
```