# Get path to desktop of ACTUAL user logged in to webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website running on a server which is located on a place far far away. The website running is in ASP.net with C#. People log in to this website daily.

Now I would like, when a logged-in person clicks on a specific button, create a folder on that person's actual desktop, with some irrelevant things in that folder.

When I use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)` and I run the program locally, it works. But when I run it from the server, the folder does not appear on my computer.

Comment: Imagine for a second the chaos that would ensue if any random website you visited could freely create files or folders on your desktop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Server.MapPath to get location outside website folder in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422270/how-to-use-server-mappath-to-get-location-outside-website-folder-in-asp-net)

Comment: @SurentharP No, that's completely different. Did you read the question?

Comment: Think for a moment: have you ever just seen a website just create folders/files on your computer at its discretion? No, you have not. You may have been given the option to download a file to your PC, or to download a program that you then run which then can download more files.

Comment: Mason, thats completely true. How do i do that then? How do i give someone the opportunity to save for example an xmlfile in THEIR computer?

Comment: @Brewsli https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057836/how-can-i-return-a-pdf-from-a-web-request-in-asp-net / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169433/how-to-properly-serve-a-pdf-file (the same principle will apply for all files you want them to download - not just pdf)

Comment: Did that help @Brewsli?

Comment: @mjwills i havent been able to try it yet. But it looks really nice. I Will get back to you when i tried it. Thank you bro!

Comment: @mjwills thanks alot! I posted an answer on how i solved it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this @mjwills and everyone else.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
xml.Save(ms);
byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();

Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xml", filename));
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```